# How do I convert CHM files to pdf?

Tags: 12.10, pdf, html, chm

Here's a list of things I've tried:

- Calibre from which I received a file containing the table of contents of the chm file with each title hyperlinked to nowhere (i.e. they're highlighted in blue and underlined).
- chm2pdf which gave me nothing and the errors:

  ```
  ERR011: Unable to parse HTML element on line 13!
  ERR002: Error: no pages generated! (did you remember to use webpage mode?
  Something wrong happened when launching htmldoc.
  exit value:  512
  Check if output exists or if it is good.
  Done.
  ```
- arCHMage and then using html to pdf converters like Prince, LyX and online ones.

Since it uses frames this appears to be tricky for such softwares.

I am running 12.10.

Comment: Are you sure the files in itself have no errors?